# How to get current route information in OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

My URLs look like:

```
www.example.com/{languagecode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

where language code is en-us, etc.

**From the OnActionExecuting event, how can I get these values?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var languagecode = filterContext.RouteData.Values["languagecode"];

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```